# How to combine 2 tables in 1 SQL request?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
A table: 
---+----------
id +  key

B table: 
-----+--------+---------
id   +  value +   key
```

"key" field in B is getting from A table.

**I need all id from A table with a 'key' which are absent in B table.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use JOIN? If I understood well, you want a full outer join (with exclusion), which is the same as a double "not in".

See picture below for more details.

[image]

Comment: Wow, Excellent! Thank you for shared!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM tablea a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableb b WHERE b.key = a.key)
```

Comment: Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1):

`NOT IN` is one way:

```
SELECT id FROM A
WHERE key NOT IN (
    SELECT key FROM B)
```

Comment: Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1):

What about a `LEFT JOIN` like

```
select a.id,a.key from A a
left join B b on a.key = b.key
where b.id is null
```

Comment: Thank you for your support!